# Why does AWS SES not need my email's credential

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm curious about how ses works. SES can send emails on behalf of my email but it never ask for the email's credential, so how does this work?

Comment: The email standard doesn't actually require any credential, it's up to the domain owner to declare the SES as their outbound mail server, and the recipient server to accept such email

Comment: Anybody can send email on the Internet that pretends to come from someone else. Lots of spammers do it. The way to verify whether an email _actually_ came from a given domain is through techniques like [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) that use DNS records to validate email senders.

Comment: I think Nhat is confused about how gmail or other public provider ask for web authentication vs email authentication.

Comment: yeah I mean I learned about DKIM, SPF and DMARC after I asked this question. It's just weird to me I can send email as anyone. But now I know that the mail box will usually check for those 3 for identification

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can send emails pretending to be anyone. That's how emails work.
But when doing so, its most likely that your mails will either end up in the receivers spam or the receivers email server/provider will outright reject the email.

If you send emails without setting up SPF or DKIM verification, the mail will most likely end up in spam because the receiving mail servers will see that DMARC verification is not passed.

However since AWS SES wants to maintain good reputation and avoid spammers from misusing their service, AWS makes it mandatory for users to verify sender email address by asking them to click on the link received in the inbox.